# frozen SSD SATAFIRM S11 "SBFM61W5"

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disc

I bought a new SSD disk "PNY C900 SSD 240 GB"

I cloned my old disk 120GB on it, when I tried to extend my system partition I discovered that the disk is frozen.

All operations from `diskpart` don'twork (format , delete partitions, delete all partition , clean ...)

The disk is defined as "SATAFIRM S11":

[image: SATAFIRM S11]

[image]

I suspect that the disk has lost it's firmware but I can't find on the internet. It is "SBFM61W5", can any one tell me what I do or where I can get this firmware or how extract it from an other disk with the same brand and model?

Comment: On most devices the code for updating a firmware is included in the currently installed firmware. So if a firmware update process fails and this code can no longer be executed the device is dead. As you have bought a new SSD I would take the SSD back to the vendor and get a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The SSD has experienced an unrecoverable internal error and the firmware
has "panicked". It is reporting the identity of the Flash controller
(Phison S11).

There is nothing you can do with software to fix this drive.

Return the disk and ask for replacement or reimbursement.

Comment: sadly you cant do that in my country , you get no replacement and no refund . i must manage it by my self , and it is not mine and i cant offered to buy new one and since it is work disk i should fix it or buy new one for them

Comment: If you can't replace the disk, as a last hope you could try the PNY [SATA SSD Toolbox and Firmware Updater](https://www.pny.com/company/support/solid-state-drives), if it can detect the disk, and if it succeeds in rewriting the firmware, and if this will help.

Answer (score -2):

The controller chip of this drive is PHISON PS3111-S11. Firmwares shouldn't be distributed to Internet since it is a commercial secret.

You will have to turn to the seller of it. But also you can try your luck on finding firmware of PS3111.